# Display a WordPress post sorted by ACF date field in Elementor Pro

Tags: php, wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

this is probably easy but I can't quite get it sorted. I have an ACF datetime field that I'm using for public notices called "relevant_date." This field exists because the homepage features a small div with the most timely, relevant-to-the-moment public notice, and I can't sort them by the normal post date because the latest post might not be the one closest to the present moment. I hope that makes sense.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Here's what I tried:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/homepage_public_notices', function( $query ) {

$today = date_i18n ('Y-m-d');

$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    array(
        'key' => 'relevant_datetime',
        'compare' => '=',
        'value' => $today,
        'type' => 'DATE',
        )
    ) );

$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value'); 
$query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
$query->set('meta_key', 'relevant_datetime');  

} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze and debug problem:

-Are you in a good action hook? I can't find it online.

-If you are in the good hook, are you getting good results without sorting?

-If you have results, then all that remains is sorting.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/homepage_public_notices', function( $query ) {
    $today = date_i18n ('Y-m-d');
    
    $meta_key = 'relevant_datetime';
    
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        array(
            'key' => $meta_key,
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => $today,
            'type' => 'DATE',
        )
    ) );
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $query->set('meta_key', $meta_key);
} );
```

As you have shown, it should work if all conditions are OK. But I would also try the following parameters:

```
// Retrieves posts by Post Status 'publish'
$query->set('post_status', 'publish');

// (boolean) - ignore sticky posts or not (optional).
$query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', false);

// (bool) Default is true - Post information cache (optional).
$query->set('cache_results', false);        

// (bool) Default is true - Post meta information cache (optional).
$query->set('update_post_term_cache', false);

// (bool) Default is true - Post term information cache (optional).
$query->set('update_post_meta_cache', false);
```

In general, you should be careful when dealing with this because many things can affect your problem. You should also play with the priority of `add_action` and increase the value above 20 or decrease it below 10.

It's also matter if you defined this in the theme or plugin. If is defined in a plugin, then it must be defined within `'plugins_loaded'`:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function( $query ) {
    add_action( 'elementor/query/homepage_public_notices', function( $query ) {
        $today = date_i18n ('Y-m-d');
        
        $meta_key = 'relevant_datetime';
        
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => $meta_key,
                'compare' => '=',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => 'DATE',
            )
        ) );
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        $query->set('meta_key', $meta_key);
        
        // Retrieves posts by Post Status 'publish'
        $query->set('post_status', 'publish');

        // (boolean) - ignore sticky posts or not (optional).
        $query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', false);

        // (bool) Default is true - Post information cache (optional).
        $query->set('cache_results', false);        

        // (bool) Default is true - Post meta information cache (optional).
        $query->set('update_post_term_cache', false);

        // (bool) Default is true - Post term information cache (optional).
        $query->set('update_post_meta_cache', false);
        
    }, 20 );
}, 20 );
```

I hope I helped you on this.